# Ansible: In block statement to execute loop condition

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

```
- name:  key
  hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - ./vars.yml
  tasks:
  - name: Loop over domains
  block:
     - name: Set_fact method has been implemented
       ansible.builtin.file:
         path: >-
          ./certificates/{item}
          state: directory 
       register: directory_name
     - name: Generate an OpenSSL private key with the default values (4098 bits, RSA)
       community.crypto.openssl_privatekey:
         path: "{{ directory_name }}/data.pem"
  loop: "{{ domains }}"
  loop_control:
      loop_var: item
```

I am trying to loop the conditions in single file.
Note: Dont use Include_vars concept to implementation.
Is any alternative is there?

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place, and since this is YAML and that indentation do matter in YAML, please fix it.

Comment: there is any alternative to use without use block statement?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to iterate a block. Instead, you can iterate included file of tasks. For example, create a file

```yaml
shell> cat create_pk.yml 
- debug:
    msg: "Create certificates/{{ item }}"
- debug:
    msg: "Create certificates/{{ item }}/data.pem"
```

The play below shows how you can iterate the list

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - include_tasks: create_pk.yml
      loop:
        - foo.com
        - bar.com
```

gives

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [include_tasks] *************************************************************************
included: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-395/create_pk.yml for localhost => (item=foo.com)
included: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-395/create_pk.yml for localhost => (item=bar.com)

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Create certificates/foo.com

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Create certificates/foo.com/data.pem

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Create certificates/bar.com

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Create certificates/bar.com/data.pem

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=6    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```